# How to get date&time using curl command?

Tags: command-line, curl

In my PC, RTC is not working, So I want Date&Time from server using `curl` command or is there any possibilities to get date and time without RTC in PC. Required format for date&time is `DDMMYYYYHHMMSS`.

Comment: I'm curious, why you need to do this using `curl`?

Comment: In my PC RTC Not working. But, i want time Stamp in my code. So i use Curl to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, `curl` makes http(s) requests. Assuming that you have a webserver listening on the machine, so you have 2 options:

1. Create a script (php/asp/node) that gives you the date and time as response to the request.
2. Get the time from server response headers.

   ```
   curl -v https://google.com/
   ```

   this will give you among other things, a line like this

   ```
   ...
   < Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 18:39:13 GMT
   ...
   ```

   With that result, you can parse and transform to the format that you want.

   ```
   dateFromServer=$(curl -v --silent https://google.com/ 2>&1 \
      | grep Date | sed -e 's/< Date: //'); date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S" -d "$dateFromServer"
   ```

   You must note the difference of GMT vs. local time, and adapt it to your needs.

**Update 2018-11-26:**
As @SopalajodeArrierez noted, it's not possible to run this when the Certificates are not updated or the time is way off the correct value, so the `--insecure` options is needed on curl command.

```
    dateFromServer=$(curl -v --insecure --silent https://google.com/ 2>&1 \
       | grep Date | sed -e 's/< Date: //'); date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S" -d "$dateFromServer"
```

Comment: getting like this not working...`root@sai:~# curl -v https://google.cl`
`* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.cl/`
`* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache`
`* Could not resolve host: google.cl`
`* Closing connection 0`
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.cl`

Comment: what about using `https://google.com/`

Comment: Not possible to run this `curl` command from some wrong date's computer (i.e: date at 2006 year): there will be a `SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid`. In this case, I have managed to solve it with the `-k` (`--insecure`) option.

Comment: I fixed one of the answers: `dateFromServer=$(curl -v --silent https://nist.time.gov/ 2>&1 \ | grep '< Date' | sed -e 's/< Date: //'); date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S" -d "$dateFromServer"`
but it would be better to use: `dateFromServer=$(curl -v --silent https://nist.time.gov/ 2>&1 \ | grep '< Date' | sed -e 's/< Date: //'); date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$dateFromServer"`
for sorting purposes (eventually).

Answer (score 4):

If you must get the time from a remote server, use an NTP server.

For example:

```
$ ntpq -c 'rv 0 clock' localhost
clock=da8b6fe7.ae195287  Thu, Mar 10 2016  9:30:39.680
```

The `clock` value is the an NTP timestamp in hex (the epoch being 01/01/1900). You can process it a bit to get an Unix timestamp which you can then use with `date`:

```
$ ntpq -c raw -c 'rv 0 clock' localhost
Output set to raw
clock=0xda8b775d.ee94c630
$ ntpq -c raw -c 'rv 0 clock' localhost | gawk -F '[ =.]' --non-decimal-data 'NR==2{printf "@%d.%d\n", $2 - 2209075200, "0x"$3}'
@1457497973.4177870717
$ ntpq -c raw -c 'rv 0 clock' localhost | gawk -F '[=.]' --non-decimal-data 'NR==2{printf "@%d.%d\n", $2 - 2209075200, "0x"$3}' | xargs date +'%d%m%Y%H%M%S' -d 
09032016100323
```

In my case, I have an NTP daemon running locally, which I could query, hence the usage of `localhost`. You could use, instead, one of the many public NTP servers, such as `ntp.ubuntu.com`.

The `awk` command reads the line, splits it on `=` and `.`, so that the three fields are `clock`, the integer part of the timestamp and the fractional part. Then, it subtracts 2209075200 (the difference in seconds between the Unix and NTP epochs, as obtained from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32578059/2072269)) from the integer part and prints both the parts in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Get the date from a HTTP response header. Remove clutter. Set the date.

```
$ date -s `curl -I 'https://google.com/' 2>/dev/null | grep -i '^date:' | sed 's/^[Dd]ate: //g'`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alternatively if you just want to print: `date -d "$(curl -sI google.com| grep -i '^date:'|cut -d' ' -f2-)"` also when I tested, `google.co` was really offset : ~20mins. others where ok though. For Info I use this to check if my VM is ntp desync (in addition of chrony checks)

Comment: `curl -ksI goo.gle | grep -iPo '^Date: \K[\S ]*'` got
`Sat, 29 Oct 2022 21:30:49 GMT`

//for people who want less pipe cmd (need grep -P PCRE support)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.
I keep a switch statement for translating from the three character month representation returned from a server to the digit value of the month. This should work on many standard Unix environments, as long as curl, echo, cut, date, and bash are installed.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Automatically Updates System Time According to the NIST Atomic Clock in a Linux Environment
    nistTime=$(curl -I --insecure 'https://nist.time.gov/' | grep "Date")
    echo $nistTime
    dateString=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f2-7)
    dayString=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f2-2)
    dateValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f3-3)
    monthValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f4-4)
    yearValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f5-5)
    timeValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f6-6)
    timeZoneValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f7-7)
    #echo $dateString
    case $monthValue in
        "Jan")
            monthValue="01"
            ;;
        "Feb")
            monthValue="02"
            ;;
        "Mar")
            monthValue="03"
            ;;
        "Apr")
            monthValue="04"
            ;;
        "May")
            monthValue="05"
            ;;
        "Jun")
            monthValue="06"
            ;;
        "Jul")
            monthValue="07"
            ;;
        "Aug")
            monthValue="08"
            ;;
        "Sep")
            monthValue="09"
            ;;
        "Oct")
            monthValue="10"
            ;;
        "Nov")
            monthValue="11"
            ;;
        "Dec")
            monthValue="12"
            ;;
        *)
            continue
    esac
    date --utc --set "$yearValue-$monthValue-$dateValue $timeValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

// for some reason `ntpdate` or `htpdate` can't work

### just share a script (for bash)

to set system date & time from curl (http response header).
// combined others answer

- curl -k (for https with wrong local time
- curl -I (use `HEAD` request more efficient, need server support
- grep -i (for server response `date:` or `Date:` ..
- grep '^Date:' (avoid other headers like `XXX-date:` ...

// need `grep -P` PCRE support
// note: grep '^Date:.*' may print nothing, cause `\r` trick the output

```sh
#!/bin/bash

url="${1:-goo.gle}"

echo "time before: `date -Is`"

echo
time=`curl -ksI "$url" | grep -iPo '^Date: \K[\S ]*'`
echo "time on net: $time"
echo "time parsed: `date -Is -d "$time"`"

[ -n "$time" ] && {
    echo
    echo "time  apply: `date -s "$time"`"
    echo "time  after: `date -Is`"
}
```

outputs:

```sh
$ sudo TZ=GMT-4 ./htpdate.sh bing.com
time before: 2022-10-30T02:10:28+04:00

time on net: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 22:10:28 GMT
time parsed: 2022-10-30T02:10:28+04:00

time  apply: Sun Oct 30 02:10:28 GMT 2022
time  after: 2022-10-30T02:10:28+04:00
```

TZ=.. to pass timezone for display (only in this script)
arg1 to pass url (default goo.gle)

Answer (score 0):

use timestamp in htttp reponse header.

```
date -d "$(curl -sI baidu.com| grep -i '^date:'|cut -d' ' -f2-)"
date -d "$(curl -sI baidu.com| grep -i '^date:'|cut -d' ' -f2-)" | xargs -I {} date --date='{}' "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
# below cmd is set new date
date -s "$(date -d "$(curl -sI baidu.com| grep -i '^date:'|cut -d' ' -f2-)" | xargs -I {} date --date='{}' "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this  (get date&time using curl), wou be:

```
CURL -s -I "https://google.com/" | FINDSTR "date:"
```

response, something like: `date: Sat, 03 Jun 2023 15:44:25 GMT`

NOTE: "something like", because time has the nature of changing quickly

or, when you just want a date:

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=3,4,5" %f in (`CURL -s -I "https://google.com/" ^| FINDSTR "date:"`) DO ECHO %f %g %h
```

output: `03 Jun 2023`